# How to resize the canvas using three-d in Rust?

Tags: rust, 3d, webassembly

```
use three_d::*;

pub fn main() {
    // Create window
    let window: Window<()> = Window::new(WindowSettings {
        title: "Shapes!".to_string(),
        ..Default::default()
    })
    .unwrap();
    let context: Context = window.gl();

    // Camera setup
    let mut camera: Camera = Camera::new_perspective(
        Viewport {
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: 480,
            height: 480,
        },
        vec3(5.0, 5.0, 5.0),
        vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0),
        degrees(45.0),
        0.1,
        100.0,
    );

    // Control setup
    let mut control = OrbitControl::new(*camera.target(), 1.0, 100.0);

    let mut sphere = Gm::new(
        Mesh::new(&context, &CpuMesh::sphere(16)),
        PhysicalMaterial::new_transparent(
            &context,
            &CpuMaterial {
                albedo: Color {
                    r: 255,
                    g: 0,
                    b: 0,
                    a: 200,
                },
                ..Default::default()
            },
        ),
    );
    sphere.set_transformation(Mat4::from_translation(vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)) * Mat4::from_scale(0.2));

    let light0 = DirectionalLight::new(&context, 1.0, Color::WHITE, &vec3(0.0, -0.5, -0.5));
    let light1 = DirectionalLight::new(&context, 1.0, Color::WHITE, &vec3(0.0, 0.5, 0.5));

    window.render_loop(move |mut frame_input| {
        camera.set_viewport(frame_input.viewport);
        control.handle_events(&mut camera, &mut frame_input.events);

        frame_input
            .screen()
            .clear(ClearState::color_and_depth(0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1.0, 1.0))
            .render(
                &camera,
                sphere
                    .into_iter(),
                &[&light0, &light1],
            );

        FrameOutput::default()
    });
}
```

Given the code how to resize the canvas width and height. I tried changing the viewpoint etc.
Please give me some insight on how to change the size of the canvas / window in Rust `three-d` library. *The width and height of the canvas is always fixed like width = "1015" and height = "750"*. How to change that?

[Screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vg82.jpg)

Thank you.